# How to pass full url parameter into main domain url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have a form with code below:

```
<form id="checkURL">
<div class="textInputBorder">
<input name="url" value="" size="120" data-placeholder="Enter Your URL Here" id="lg-search">
</div>            
<input id="lg-searchBtn" value="GO" type="submit">
</form>
```

I would like to pass url (from input with name: url) into my domain url, for example

My Domain : my-domain.com

Extra url : http://www.extra-domain.com/group/world-test-35002158

I would like to make url like this after enter url and submit [GO]

[*] http://my-domain.com/www.extra-domain.com/group/world-test-35002158

This page [*] has an iframe src= http ://www.extra-domain.com/group/world-test-35002158

Please help me !

Thanks

P/S : i am using PHP and .htaccess

Comment: in 2nd domain name www. came in middle how is this possible.

Comment: @ANSHULGERA I do believe he is trying to make a redirect service.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add that to the PHP that uses the post parameters. Something along the lines of:

```
$str = "http://my-domain.com/" . $_POST['url'];
```

Comment: I want thas page has an iframe src= http ://www.extra-domain.com/group/world-test-35002158

Comment: As far as I know, you can not change anything inside of an iframe.

Comment: I want my page to work like  http://responsivedesignchecker.com/www.google.com
 
Where:  
- http://responsivedesignchecker.com/ is MY-DOMAIN.COM 
- www.google.com is EXTRA-DOMAIN.COM